# How to POST data using API in Postman

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am creating an API by using spring boot. Basically, this API does CRUD operations. And also I created a client that consumes my own API. At first I use Postman to POST data, it successfully insert data to the database and gives me 200 OK code. Then I created web page and I use my API as form action. Then I tried to insert data using the API. But, couldn't. Then I removed @RequestBody from the method and after that I was able to insert data. But the thing is now I can't insert data using Postman. When I try to insert data using Postman, it gives me 200 OK, but nothing insert to the database.

How can I Fix this ??

```
package com.kisalka.pacrestapi.controller;

import java.util.List;

import javax.validation.Valid;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.*;

import com.kisalka.pacrestapi.repository.ImRepository;
import com.kisalka.pacrestapi.model.ImModel;

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class ImController {

    @Autowired
    private ImRepository TaskRepository;


    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/tasks")
    public ImModel createNote(ImModel note) {
        return TaskRepository.save(note);
    }

}
```

My web page.

```
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Project Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="pname" id="txtPname"/>
                        </div>              
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Developer Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-7">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="devname" id="txtDevname"/>
                        </div>              
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Save" id="btnRegister"/>
                    </div>

                </form>
```

Comment: Do you hit API endpoint when you make POST request from Postman? If yes, can you check in debug mode what do you have in your note variable when endpoint is hit? if it's null, then something is wrong with your POST request payload

Comment: I didn't understand what you said..Im very new to API development and spring boot..

Comment: Do you know how to debug Java code? Basically how to set breakpoints and check current variables values on the run.

Comment: Nop.. But, at first I use Postman to POST data, it successfully insert data to the database and gives me 200 OK code.

Answer (score 0):

In one of your `@Configuration` classes or `@EnableAutoConfiguration` class create a bean of `CommonsRequestLoggingFilter`, paste the code. This will log every incoming request

```
@Bean
public CommonsRequestLoggingFilter logFilter() {
    CommonsRequestLoggingFilter filter
      = new CommonsRequestLoggingFilter();
    filter.setIncludeQueryString(true);
    filter.setIncludePayload(true);
    filter.setMaxPayloadLength(10000);
    filter.setIncludeHeaders(false);
    filter.setAfterMessagePrefix("REQUEST DATA : ");
    return filter;
}
```

And in your `application.properties` file set logging level to DEBUG using `logging.level.org.springframework.web.filter.CommonsRequestLoggingFilter=
  DEBUG`

All set! now call your endpoint from the WEB/Postman and check if you find the missing piece.

Comment: I added @Bean in my controller and added this code to properties. But, still I cant use Postman to POST data. How can I Fix this ??

Comment: What is it that you see in logs?
Also, i request you to try POSTing using `Content-Type` as ,`x-www-form-urlencoded` OR `form-data` instead of `application/json` in Postman.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `@RequestBody` :

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/tasks")
public ImModel createNote(@RequestBody ImModel note) {
   return TaskRepository.save(note);
 }
```

Comment: At first I use Postman to POST data, it successfully insert data to the database and gives me 200 OK code. Then I created web page and I use my API as form action. Then I tried to insert data using the API. But, couldn't. Then I removed @RequestBody from the method and after that I was able to insert data. But the thing is now I can't insert data using Postman. When I try to insert data using Postman, it gives me 200 OK, but nothing insert to the database.

Answer (score 0):

use the code written below.You need to add @RequestBody before ImModel note

```
 @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value="/tasks")
    public ImModel createNote(@RequestBody ImModel note) {
        return TaskRepository.save(note);
    }
```

Comment: At first I use Postman to POST data, it successfully insert data to the database and gives me 200 OK code. Then I created web page and I use my API as form action. Then I tried to insert data using the API. But, couldn't. Then I removed @RequestBody from the method and after that I was able to insert data. But the thing is now I can't insert data using Postman. When I try to insert data using Postman, it gives me 200 OK, but nothing insert to the database.